# Probability that a bitstring of length $25$ will contain atleast two $1$s

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We choose a bitstring of length $25$ uniformly at random. What is the probability that this
string contains at least two $1$s?

(a) $1 − \left(\frac12\right)^{25} − 25\left(\frac12\right)^{25}$

(b) $1 + \left(\frac12\right)25 − 25\left(\frac12\right)25$

(c) $\sum^{25}_{k=2}\binom{25}k\left(\frac12\right)^k$

(d) none of the above

So it is a probability so it is going to be $1-$ so $C$ is not part of the problem.

choosing a string of len(25)  is expressed as $2^{25}$ but I do not know how I can express it if it contains two $1$s

Comment: Can you find the probability that it contains no $1$s? The probability that it contains exactly one $1$ (in any of the $25$ possible positions)? The probability you need is that of non-occurrence of both of these.

Comment: You can also use the binomial distribution here. So $P(\text{at least two two's})=1-P(\text{less than two two's})=1-P(0)-P(1)=1-{25\choose 0}{(\frac{1}{2}^0)(\frac{1}{2}^{25})}-{25\choose 1}{\frac{1}{2}^{25}}=1-{\frac{1}{2}}^{25}-25(\frac{1}{2})^{25}$. Under the assumption that the only bits are 0 and 1 and that each one has a fair chance of appearing so it follows that it be 1/2.

Answer (score 1):

It would be (a). If we have no bits, then $\binom{25}{0} = 1$, and so $(\frac{1}{2})^{25}$ gives the probability of no ones. Similarly, $\binom{25}{1} = 25$ counts the number of strings with one bit. So $25(\frac{1}{2})^{25}$ gives the probability of one bit.

These two cases are disjoint, so by rule of sum, we add them: $(\frac{1}{2})^{25} + 25(\frac{1}{2})^{25}$.

We then subtract this sum from $1$, the total probability.

Note: (c) would be correct if the exponent on the fraction was $25$, not $k$. Then you would have the binomial distribution formula.

Answer (score 0):

(b) is $-299$.  This is in the interval from $0$ to $1$ so it is not a probability.

You have rejected (c).  It is in fact $\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{25}-1-\frac{25}{2} \gt 25237$ and so is also not in that interval and so is not a probability.  A correct form would be $\sum^{25}_{k=2}\binom{25}k\left(\frac12\right)^{25}$ so (c) is wrong because it has the wrong exponent of $\frac12$.  Another correct answer could be $\dfrac{\sum^{25}_{k=2}\binom{25}k}{2^{25}}$.

That leaves (a) or (d).

(a) is correct as it subtracts the probability of no $1$s or one $1$ from $1$, using the binomial distribution.